# Change text colour of scrolling logo

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have a sticky logo which when I scroll stays the same colour. I want the logo to initially be white and change colour only when the background is white to black... and stay black until it sees a darker background again and then go back to white. The problem with what I currently have is that `mix-blend-mode: difference;` changes to all sorts of colours as it inverts based on background.

```
.logo {
    color: white;
    filter: invert(1);
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

Comment: Why you tagged React?

Comment: Mistake, removed it now